# VM and SQL Database on Microsoft Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Can someone explain which Microsoft Azure services I really need in order to run SQL database in that cloud environment?

**SQL Database** as a service is needed and that should be added to the pricing calculator.

Beside this, do I need to add **virtual machine (VM)** and **Storage**?

Following my own logic I should add VM and Storage too. My logic says SQL Database must be hosted on some machine (that's why I need VM) and that machine must have some storage space to host data.

If someone can explain me this it will be appreciated.

Comment: If you buy SQL Azure you don't need a VM. You need the VM only if you want to install SQL Server yourself. That's clearly explained on Azure's site, SQL Azure's pages, documentation etc

Comment: You need to understand two important concepts in the cloud before you proceed:  Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) and Platform as a Service (PaaS).  Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas).

Comment: It's clear now what is a difference and how it works. Thanks